# What's advantages and disadvantage of two different approaches to control a component in Vue?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, architecture, frontend, vuejs3

I have created two components that show "on" or "off" text and a button that switches a  state of the both components.

Link to codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-mclean-1hychc?file=/src/views/Home.vue

These components have the same behavior, but the realization is different:

- For the first component I use props to pass the state from the parent component to a child and the parent controls child's state
- For the second component I keep state inside the child component and share method to toggle state to the parent component using defineExpose

What are advantages and disadvantages of each approach?

Comment: I like the second way more, since it is better separated from the parent. But there is no better solution here. It depends more on the task you are trying to solve. And it's also very opinionated.

Comment: You will possibly get -1 for such a question and it will be closed. Check on requirements for a [suitable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) SO question

Comment: @Tolbxela I have seen questions about advantages or disadvantages of some different approaches on SO with a lot of votes. My question has the same structure, so I think it is suitable. It is not a discussion question, answer can be a list of points.

Comment: In my opinion, Vue has a clear concept of how data should flow through the system, which is (mainly) through props and events. This directly influences how components are written and where data and functionality resides, so it is a substantial part of the framework. Calling a method on a component through a template ref actively breaks this, which might be ok as a means of last resort, but overall, would make me suspect that there is an inability to work within the confines of the system. I think template refs smell. Again: opinion opinion opinion, but there you go.

Comment: Calling child components methods through ref is indeed a bad practice and should be avoided at all cost. This breaks components isolations and the Vue recommendation of using props + events as the inputs/outputs of a component. Components should be treated as grey box, where you only know about there exposed props & events, not about there internal methods.

Comment: @Kapcash If you look at the code, then you can find that in case of template ref usage, the child component provides only exposed method as an interface, while its internal state is private. In case of using props&events, the parent component should implement additional methods and hold the child's state.

Comment: @Kapcash Doesn't keeping child's state in the parent break component isolation as well?

Comment: @Moritz, if this was opinion based jQuery would still be considered a good option. It's not opinion based. There are real disadvantages to the second method which directly and indirectly translate into maintenance cost increases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should avoid calling a child's method via its `$ref`, as it has severe disadvantages:

**A. It's a form of DOM manipulation**
Simply put, this is the way we used to do things in jQuery.
In Vue, state/data drives change and you leave DOM rendering, updating and optimisation to Vue. Not because it's not possible otherwise, but because it affects development and maintenance costs in direct proportion with the app's complexity and size.
Calling a child component method from the parent means the change cannot be performed unless the child is in DOM, whereas when the parent changes the data directly it doesn't need to worry about the child being rendered.

**B. It's a form of tight coupling and it breaks component isolation**
Once you start allowing outer components calling a component's methods you severe limit your refactoring capabilities, making both future changes and testing more complex (changing the child's method might imply changes in every component using its method and possibly their tests). You increase the costs of maintenance without benefit.
Last, but not least, breaking isolation increases debugging and optimisation costs.

---

In a real-world scenario, you should ask other questions before asking the current one:

- do you need a parent/child relation there?
- can you refactor so that one of them doesn't need to perform the change, ever?
- if both need to be able to make the change and they need to stay in sync, is it possible to move the method into a composable/helper function, where it would be imported from into each parent and child and then use `v-model` to keep data in sync?

In most (if not all) cases, answering the above questions would solve the problem before you are in the position to ask the current one.

As a general rule, you should limit coupling. In layman's terms, *you want the child to know as little as possible about the parent and the parent to know as little as possible about the child*. When they do need to inform each other, limit the surface between their communication and use a well established pattern (e.g: `v-model` if the child needs to inform the parent, `props` otherwise).
When you can't achieve the desired functionality without using a custom pattern, consider using a store or refactor to achieve encapsulation/isolation.

I can't stress enough how big an impact this rule has on speed of development and, ultimately, on development costs, as the maintenance-free app doesn't exist. It's a myth. Every real-world app needs change in some shape of form and the above rule deeply impacts the time and effort needed to change, test, debug and optimise your apps.

Answer (score 2):

If it's something as simple as `Label` which has no logic at all, use Component1.
. Because inserting unneded logic into basically stateless components is bad design

If it's something as advanced as `Dialog` which has a lot of logic and exposed functions, use Component2.
. Because if the componend is often created by script and has tens of exposed functions there is no other choice.

If it's something in-between such as `Toggle`, use two-way bindings
. Because if you need two-way binding, you use two-way binding.

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
import { useVModel } from '@vueuse/core'

const props = defineProps<{
  on: string
  off: string
  modelValue: string
}>()
const emit = defineEmits(['update:modelValue'])

const val = useVModel(props, 'modelValue', emit)

const defaultText = 'Off';

</script>

<template>
  <div @click="val = !val">
    {{ val ? on ?? '[on]' : off ?? 'off' }}
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Is there any performance difference between these approaches? Is defineExpose fast enough?

Comment: @pepeevich you will never have ANY performance problems in Vue unless you watch a dynamicly sorted 1000+-length array (I did that -_-). For the simple function calls there isalmost no overhead same as for everything else.

Comment: @pepeevich tried to explain.

Comment: thank you for the answer @Dimava. I mean is there any performance DIFFERENCE if I will use the first or the second way within the whole app.

Comment: @pepeevich NO, it's exactly the same. Same as making a ref an using $refs is exactly the same. Same as ref and reactive performance is exactly the same. That's like viewing the elephant from different sides: it looks different, but it's the same elephant.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is opinion based question and My answer would be `"It totally depends on the requirement"`.

I know just for a demo purpose you created a toggle scenario and based on that scenario, first approach is a good one and proficient.

Instead of listing advantages/disadvantages, Let me explain the use case of both the approaches with the example **:**

**Approach 1 :** Using of props/events to communicate between the components.

If you have to just pass some data from parent to make decisions based on the passed param then you should go with this approach and this is the best practice to do that.

[image]

**Approach 2 :** Expose and invoke the child component method using `ref` from parent component.

If you have to perform some logic in the child component by triggering an event in parent then I think this is a good approach to follow.

[image]

Comment: Oh, I am not sure if this is good advice. At least to me, it reads like "use props/events, unless you feel it is easier not to", but I think it should be "do not use template refs unless there is absolutely no other way". Your second example can be easily transformed into a props/event structure, and I think it absolutely should. Yes, rules are made to be broken, but not willy-nilly at the first sign of inconvenience. So I guess I have to agree, it is an opinion-based question.

Comment: @MoritzRingler Yes right! It's totally depends on the requirement and opinion. That's the reason I just explained with an example and use cases.